# jquery .find callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering is there a way to get a callback from a jquery .find function.

So it would be

```
$('#Div').find($('.items')).each(function () {}).Callback(function(){//Do stuff});
```

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: What do you want to do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A callback is generally a function that is passed to another function that will perform a long-running, typically a non-blocking, task. The callback is then invoked when the non-blocking task is completed.

Since `.each` is blocking, your code is going to execute linearly. You could simply write

```
$('#Div').find($('.items')).each(function () {})
// Do stuff
```